# DLL not injecting?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a dll injector in C# winforms but it doesn't seem to work. You select a process from a list then you choose your dll. The process and dll path is correct and everything returns something correctly except CreateRemoteThread which returns 0. If that is the problem, how do I fix it? I tested with a 64-bit program and dll too. Here is my code:

```
private void Inject(string DllPath, Process InjectProcess)
        {
            IntPtr hProcess = Win32.OpenProcess(1082, false, InjectProcess.Id);
            Console.WriteLine(hProcess);
            IntPtr procAddress = Win32.GetProcAddress(Win32.GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
            Console.WriteLine(procAddress);
            uint num = (uint)((DllPath.Length + 1) * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char)));
            Console.WriteLine(num);
            IntPtr intPtr = Win32.VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, num, 12288U, 4U);
            Console.WriteLine(intPtr);
            UIntPtr uintPtr;
            Console.WriteLine(Win32.WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, intPtr, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(DllPath), num, out uintPtr));
            
            Console.WriteLine(Win32.CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, 0U, procAddress, intPtr, 0U, IntPtr.Zero));
            MessageBox.Show("Injected " + this.openFileDialog1.SafeFileName + " into Process " + this.listBox1.GetItemText(this.listBox1.SelectedItem) + "!");
        }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string processname = this.listBox1.GetItemText(this.listBox1.SelectedItem);
            Process[] chosenprocess = Process.GetProcessesByName(processname); 
            this.Inject(this.openFileDialog1.FileName, chosenprocess[0]);
        }

public static class Win32
{
    // Token: 0x06000012 RID: 18
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern int SuspendThread(IntPtr hThread);

    // Token: 0x06000013 RID: 19
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern int ResumeThread(IntPtr hThread);

    // Token: 0x06000014 RID: 20
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenThread(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwThreadId);

    // Token: 0x06000015 RID: 21
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hHandle);

    // Token: 0x06000016 RID: 22
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    // Token: 0x06000017 RID: 23
    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

    // Token: 0x06000018 RID: 24
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    // Token: 0x06000019 RID: 25
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

    // Token: 0x0600001A RID: 26
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out UIntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    // Token: 0x0600001B RID: 27
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes, uint dwStackSize, IntPtr lpStartAddress, IntPtr lpParameter, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpThreadId);
}
```

Comment: And the result from `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` after every function call is...?

Comment: It returns 5.
Isn't that a permission error?

Comment: [`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) Are you running as administrator? Perhaps try running it as a scheduled task as SYSTEM

Comment: I tried running as administrator already.

Comment: It gives error code 6 when I run it as administrator even though the process id is correct.

Comment: On which function, CreateRemoteThread? Is that the only one that returns something from GetLastWin32Error?  By the way, given that you are using `LoadLibraryA`, you probably want `Encoding.ASCII`

Comment: GetProcAddress creates the error.